# How to change background color for markdowns fenced code blocks?

Tags: colorscheme

I can do this for markdown's tab-based code blocks with `mkdCode` color group. So my question is if it's possible to do the same for fenced once?

I use [plasticboy/vim-markdown](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown) plugin.

Here's a minimal vim config to reproduce the behaviour `~/.config/nvim/test-init.vim`:

```
filetype plugin indent on
call plug#begin()
Plug 'plasticboy/vim-markdown', {'for': 'markdown'}
call plug#end()
highlight mkdCode ctermbg=yellow
```

Here's the result I get with it:

[image]

It seems that after applying `mkdCode` background it rewrites by code highlighting.

Comment: Looks like you're using the vim-markdown plug-in. Yes, it should highlighting fenced code blocks with `mkdCode` too, see [this rule](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown/blob/da5a7ac96f517e0fd6f886bc3fbe27156ca1f946/syntax/markdown.vim#L103) which matches <code>\`\`\`</code> on its own line to match start and end of the block... Is that not working for you? Can you show an example of it not working?

Comment: @filbranden right, sorry I forgot to mention about the plugin, I've updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use a technique I picked up on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/fob3sg/different_background_color_for_markdown_code/) from */u/fob3sg*:

````
function! ColorCodeBlocks() abort " {{{1
  setlocal signcolumn=no

  sign define codeblock linehl=codeBlockBackground

  augroup code_block_background
    autocmd! * <buffer>
    autocmd InsertLeave  <buffer> call s:place_signs()
    autocmd BufEnter     <buffer> call s:place_signs()
    autocmd BufWritePost <buffer> call s:place_signs()
  augroup END
endfunction

function! s:place_signs()
  let l:continue = 0
  let l:file = expand('%')

  execute 'sign unplace * file=' . l:file

  for l:lnum in range(1, line('$'))
    let l:line = getline(l:lnum)
    if l:continue || l:line =~# '^\s*```'
      execute printf('sign place %d line=%d name=codeblock file=%s',
            \ l:lnum, l:lnum, l:file)
    endif

    let l:continue = l:continue
          \ ? l:line !~# '^\s*```$'
          \ : l:line =~# '^\s*```'
  endfor
endfunction
````

This creates a function that (mis)uses the signcolumn feature to change the background color of code blocks. To use it, add something like this e.g. in your `after/ftplugin/markdown.vim`:

```
highlight codeBlockBackground ctermbg=yellow
call ColorCodeBlocks()
```

I find it actually works very well. Obviously, you can change the color to something that fits your colorscheme.

Comment: In order for this to work, you'll need to copy the function `MarkdownBlocks` from the linked reddit post and rename it to `s:place_signs`. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I've added the `s:place_signs` function to the answer now.

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to remove the gutter, e.g. when using ALE, errors / warnings are no longer indicated next to the line where they appear. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: The gutter (i.e. signcolumn!) is removed because of the `set signcolumn=no` statement. Just comment that out/remove that line if you want to keep the gutter visible.

Comment: (Although, perhaps this method will clear the gutter because of the `sign unplace ...`. One possibility here would be to rely on the sign groups, see `:help sign-place` and `:help sign-unplace` for more info.)

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing here is vim-markdown's support for highlighting embedded languages in fenced code blocks.

In short, vim-markdown will recognize the `python` in ```` ```python ```` and it will use Python syntax highlighting for that code block.

You can find the code that implements that [here](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown/blob/da5a7ac96f517e0fd6f886bc3fbe27156ca1f946/ftplugin/markdown.vim#L700).

It will create a new syntax highlighting group `mkdSnippetPYTHON` and have that block include Python syntax rules.

In theory, you could change the background of that specific group:

```
highlight mkdSnippetPYTHON ctermbg=yellow
```

But I found that doesn't really work great, since Python keywords (such as `if`, `while`, `def`, etc.) and other highlighted terms (such as function names in a function definition) will have been styled by Python and will override your background setting, showing a normal background.

Note that this doesn't happen if you don't have a language in your fenced block, if you start it with only ```` ``` ```` or if you have it for a language that's invalid or not recognized. (If you really wanted to keep the `python` language tag but not use syntax highlighting here, perhaps mapping `'python'` to an invalid value in `g:vim_markdown_fenced_languages` would be a somewhat hacky way to disable this behavior.)

Comment: Yeah, I've just played a bit with it too and couldn't find a simple solution to make the background consistent. But now I understand you it works, thanks :)